# Handling bounces using Sendgrid or Mailjet API

Tags: exm

We are currently using custom SMTP provider with Sitecore EXM 3.3. As we know from Sitecore Support, Sitecore handles all bounces (that are read through POP3) as hard bounces in custom SMTP scenario.

We are currently investigating option to consume event APIs for either Sendgrid or MailJet which provide bounce api but don;t know whether we can somehow use Sitecore API (EXM API) to set bounces on contacts based on email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to customize the bounce handling, your best option would be to implement a custom IPop3ReceiversCollection and IPop3BounceReceiver.

The IPop3ReceiversCollection is defined in the receiversCollection element of /App_Config/Include/EmailExperience/Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSMTP.Sync.config, by default Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.Reporting.Pop3ReceiversCollection which uses a Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.Reporting.ChilkatPop3BounceReceiver to process the actual messages.

The ChilkatPop3BounceReceiver is what's actually determining if it's a hard bounce or not.

Unfortunately you cannot replace ChilkatPop3BounceReceiver as Pop3ReceiversCollection is hardcoded to use it, so you will have to override both.

Comment: This is a great approach but we are aiming not to use POP3 to get bounced email messages. We are planning to use https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#events and their bounce events. So once bounce event is consumed, we need to track this on recipient in Sitecore. Something that Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.Reporting.ChilkatPop3BounceReceiver is doing in MapToBounce method.

Comment: You don't need to use POP3 if you implement your own IPop3BounceReceiver. Just pretend the name is IBounceReceiver ;) You just need to process the bounces (e.g. pull from SendGrid/Mailjet API)  and then create Sitecore.EDS.Core.Reporting.Bounce's, setting the BounceType to hard/soft